# Calling other nodes in a Curator Leader Election example

Tags: java, apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Taking the [Example leader selector code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=curator.git;a=tree;f=curator-examples/src/main/java/leader;h=73b547eadb98995c0ccbd06a5b76d0741ffef263;hb=HEAD) of **Apache Curator**, it's easy to perform some tasks while being the leader, but how can we give tasks to other participants in the leader election process?

For example, if a node has the method

```
void doWork(){
  System.out.println(1);
}
```

I'd like to have the leader telling this other participant node to perform the work, how could I do so?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what there is that you actually want to do?
And we might be able to help you find some way of achieving that.
Do you want the leader to hand out tasks or do you want the other nodes to do background work while not being leaders?

Comment: I'd like to have both possibilities, and it would be perfect if the leader could explicitly call the other nodes to do some work.
What I'd like to have: _n_ nodes (the same class **Java**) who are participating in the **Curator** LeaderElection, and when one of them take the lead, the other nodes stay active and the leader can pass orders to them (so when a node take the leadership I'd like to have a master/workers model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not go into detail about how you should solve this but instead give a crude example of how it could be done. Lets first add a method to the ExampleClient that does some work in a new thread.

```
public boolean active;
public void doWork(){
    active = true;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(active){
                System.out.println("Working");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
public void stopWork(){
    active = false;
}
```

Now you can call doWork on any ExampleClient object you might have and it will start working, and to stop it you call stopWork.
If we add doWork() to start() and stopWork() to takeLeadership() we will have a class that works until it becomes leader and then stops.

To start and stop other nodes from the leader I would suggest having a look at 'message passing' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing but I again give you a crude way of doing it:

If we add this to ExampleClient:

```
public List<ExampleClient> nodes;
@Override
public void takeLeadership(CuratorFramework client) throws Exception
{
    // we are now the leader. This method should not return until we want to relinquish leadership
    for(ExampleClient e : nodes){
      if(this != e)
        e.doWork();
    }
    ...
```

and this to LeaderSelectorExample:

```
examples.add(example);
example.nodes = examples;   //New line
client.start();
example.start();
```

The leader will make the other nodes do some work.

This is not the best way of doing it, but I think it's a good start, and something you could improve upon and learn from.

Comment: So we have to start another thread in doWork()?
I'm considering other options like using listeners and creating some Znodes when having new tasks, using [Path Cache](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/path-cache.html), or [Distributed Queue](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/distributed-queue.html) to do so.
Do you advise to go further in **Zookeeper** rather than using **Curator recipes**?

Comment: If you call it as a method from another ExampleClient you have to start a thread if you want them to work side by side.
I would advice using Curator rather then raw Zookeeper.

Comment: I have a last question:  I'd like to run one client per process, and the 
obvious solution would be to update the list is to do `private static List<ExampleClient> examples = Lists.newArrayList();`
Would you have another way to do so instead of creating a static list?

Comment: I can't answer that question given the example-code you've referenced. Making the list **examples** static would not change the execution of the example since the list is only used inside the main method.